# Fetch the row of next in rank to the “rank of last id”?

Tags: php

Need help!

Mysql query:

```
CREATE TABLE goal_implement( id INT, percent INT ); 

INSERT INTO goal_implement VALUES 
  (1,10),
  (2,15),
  (3,20),
  (4,40),
  (5,50),
  (6,20);
```

My PHP code - this code display the result table below....

```
<?php
$query2 = "SELECT _id, percent, FIND_IN_SET( percent, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( percent
ORDER BY percent DESC ) 
FROM goal_implement )
) AS rank
FROM goal_implement 
ORDER BY id DESC 
";
```

I want this block to be on focus for the comment: I need the php code; NOT mysql query...

```
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection);
if($result2 === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td>{$row['id']}</td>
<td>{$row['percent']}</td>
<td> {$row['rank']} </td>    
</tr>\n";       
} 
?>
```

Result:

```
id  percent rank
6   20      3
5   50      1
4   40      2
3   20      3
2   15      5
1   10      6
```

I don't know how to fetch the row(rank) that is next on the last id for example: last id's rank is 3!I want the result Below.....

Desired result using PHP:

```
4   40      2
```

Comment: Can't understand the phrase "last id's rank" and don't see the logic. Why is the desired result the id=4 line?

Comment: @KoalaYeung - The last id(6) --> rank(3)...I want to display the id whose rank (2).... "the next in rank"

Comment: Is the rank unique? Will there be duplicated rank?

Comment: if there percent is tie.. then there is duplicate... as you can see above: @rank 3 there is tie,,,, but there isnt rank 4 bcoz of the tie..

Comment: So there php will show 2 lines if the last id rank is 4, right?

Comment: @KoalaYeung - i guess mam... its always based in the last id's rank....if the last id's rank is 2... then display whose rank is in 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
<?php

$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection);
if($result2 === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

// store rows by rank
// also get the last_id_rank from the first row
$by_ranks = array();
$last_id_rank = FALSE;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $by_ranks[$row['rank']][] = $row;
    if ($last_id_rank === FALSE) {
        $last_id_rank = $row['rank'];
    }
}

// get the results
$get_results = function($by_ranks, $last_id_rank) {

    // get a sorted array of that's smaller than $last_id_rank
    $ranks = array_filter(array_keys($by_ranks), function($var) use($last_id_rank) {
        return $var < $last_id_rank;
    });
    rsort($ranks); // sort ranks by descending order

    // get the rank that is just smaller than $last_id_rank
    if (sizeof($ranks) == 0) {
        return array();
    } else {
        return $by_ranks[$ranks[0]];
    }

};
$results = $get_results($by_ranks, $last_id_rank);

// display results
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$row['id']}</td>
        <td>{$row['percent']}</td>
        <td> {$row['rank']} </td>    
        </tr>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man... it works!! some question:   what if the row you want to display is tie; then the two tie row will display... how to display only one row from the tie

Comment: That was the purpose of my previous questions. I assumed, by your answers, that multiple rows should be displayed in case of tie. You may simply change the last foreach to display only 1 row. It should be very easy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mysql_fetch_array()`, why don't you use it's index?

```
$row['rank'][$incrementHere]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing we can filter data with `HAVING` clause

```
$query="SELECT id, percent, FIND_IN_SET( percent, (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( percent
ORDER BY percent DESC )
FROM goal_implement )
) AS rank
FROM goal_implement
HAVING id >".$last_id_rank."
ORDER BY id ASC limit 1";
```