# Calculate the Student Rank

Tags: php, rank

I have followed the previous question and answer through this link:
[Fetch the row of next in rank to the “rank of last id”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722400/php-only-fetch-the-row-of-next-in-rank-to-the-rank-of-last-id)

Sadly, I couldn't get the result as I expected. 
The expected result:

```
id  score rank
 1   78    4
 2   80    3
 3   100   1
 4   88    2
 5   56    5
```

In database, I have the id, score in my table: result. 
Now, what I am trying is too put the rank in the table.

My code is as below:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ranking</title>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if($db){
                //Create Query
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM result ORDER BY score DESC";

                //Execute Query
                $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


                if($result -> num_rows > 0){                  

                    //output data for each row
                    echo " 
                        <br><br>                        
                        <table align='center'; border=1; style='text-align:center'>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan='4'>RANKING TABLE</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Bil</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Result</th>
                                <th>Rank</th>
                            </tr>
                        ";

                    $i = 0;
                    //Store rows by rank + get the last_id_rank from the first row
                    $by_ranks = array();
                    $last_id_rank = FALSE;

                    //Display Result
                    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
                        $i++;

                        echo " 
                            <tr>
                                <td>".$i."</td>
                                <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                                <td>".$row["score"]."</td>
                                <td>".$row["rank"]."</td>
                            </tr>
                        ";

                        $by_ranks[$row["rank"]][]=$row;
                        if($last_id_rank === FALSE){
                            $last_id_rank = $row["rank"];
                        }
                    }

                    //Get the result
                    $get_results = function($by_ranks, $last_id_rank){
                        //Get sorted array that's smaller $last_id_rank
                        $ranks = array_filter(array_keys($by_ranks),function($var) use ($last_id_rank){
                            return $var < $last_id_rank;
                        });
                        rsort($ranks); //Sort ranks by DESC

                        //Get rank that is just smaller than $last_id_rank
                        if(sizeof($ranks) == 0){
                            return array();
                        }
                        else{
                            return $by_ranks[$ranks [0]];
                        }
                    };

                    $results = $get_results($by_ranks,$last_id_rank);

                    //Display results
                    foreach($results as $row){
                        echo "
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{$row["id"]}</td>
                                <td>{$row["score"]}</td>
                                <td>{$row["rank"]}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ";
                    }                 


                    echo "
                        </table>
                    ";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Failed to connect";
                mysqli_close($db);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The data in my database is as below:

```
id  score rank
 1   78    0
 2   80    0
 3   100   0
 4   88    0
 5   56    0
```

Comment: So you dont have "rank" field in database, you just want to output it in php, right?

Comment: I have 'rank' field in database but without any number in database yet. Wish to have the rank (output) in database and display in php.

Comment: So in some shorthand something like this?
// SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY score DESC
$i = 0;
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $i++;
    $result['rank'] = $i;
    $db->query("UPDATE yourtable SET rank = '" . $result['rank'] . "' WHERE id = " . $result['id']);
}

Comment: your code is showing the rank returned from the database. You first miss the part where you calculate it and update the database (to be run before creating the table to have updated data

Comment: Sorry, I quite confuse for this statement '$results as &$results', won't it be conflict? since my code $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql); has been used for sorting according score.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta, do you mean I have to calculate the rank first before enter the information into database ? But isn't it have to go through the previous list first, so the latest rank result can be released, is it ?

Comment: you are just printing what is in your database. You say rank is 0 in your database so how can you echo the real ranking? You have to calculate it no?

Comment: Alright, that's what I'm trying to update the rank. But I really feel lost to do create the calculation

Comment: Calculating and updating the rank in the database can be done with a single query. Give me acouple minutes and I'll write up what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Given your table structure, you could update the table to have rank values with the following:

```
UPDATE result
LEFT JOIN result AS sub
 ON sub.score > result.score
SET rank = COUNT(sub.id) + 1
```

The left join does the comparison with other rows in the table and setting the rank to the count with a higher score plus one gives you ranks starting at 1 instead of 0. Also, if you want ties to get the lowest rank that any of them would have, just change sub.score > result.score to use >=

Once you have your data in place, you can just access the rank values in php from the result of your SQL query and don't need to do calculations on the fly.

Comment: I tried this code in my SQL (phpMyadmin). It came out error as below: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN result AS sub ON sub.score > result.score' at line 3

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake, I put the set before the join. Will fix

Comment: It's ok. Anyway, Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

To create the result required from a table containing only id and score you could do the following.

```
select * from(
 select id,score,(@rank:=@rank+1) as rank 
 from tbl 
 cross join
 ( select @rank:=0 ) T1
 order by score desc
) T2
order by id
;
```

which results in

```
id  score   rank
1   78      4
2   80      3
3   100     1
4   88      2
5   56      5
```